# How to replace a button with an image?

Tags: css

I'm creating a floating sidebar which will display Facebook logo and open a `div` on click. This `div` will contain a Facebook like box. When the user clicks the logo again, the `div` closes.

I managed to get it working, but I need to replace the button with an image (Facebook logo, like I said) and still have the functionality of this script.

How could I achieve this?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/h8CNP

Comment: why not use img tag instead of the button?

Comment: I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h8CNP/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Javascript is set to toggle based on the click of the `id` so all you would need to do is replace this:

```
<button id="show1" data-href="curtir">Click ME!</button>
```

With this:

```
<img id="show1" src="whatever.jpg" data-href="curtir" />
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/LrTqG/

Comment: I dont understand previous answers offering image backgrounds and stuff. Upvote for common sense.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Thanks! Yeah, no need to go crazy with it when a simple `img` tag works fine.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. Dryden, this was the easiest and best way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply an image on button using below css code.

```
button {
  border: none;
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/100/50") 0 0;
  width: 100px;
  height:50px;
}
```

Here is a ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h8CNP/4/)***

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in several ways, one is to put background image to button like this:

```
<button id="show1" data-href="curtir" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-image: url(http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/150/i/2013/012/c/6/rock_01_png___by_alzstock-d5r84up.png); background-size: 100% 100%;"></button>
```

or use img element instead of button

or use div with background image that reacts on click... (my favorite because it can be transparent, no borders etc...)

of course, for img and div you would want to change cursor to pointer

```
style="cursor: pointer;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the button to remove the inner text `<button id="show1" data-href="curtir"></button>` and add something like the following CSS code

```
#show1 {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/100x50') no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

You can add borders for hover too!

```
#show1:hover {
    border: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

And for some effect of pushing the button down:

```
#show1:active {
    background-position: 1px 1px;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8CNP/10/)

Answer (score 0):

how about making using of the "image" input type?

```
<input type="image" src="http://epicshowdowns.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/facebook-icon.png" id="show1" data-href="curtir" value="Click ME!" />
<div id="curtir" class="demo">Lorem ipsum.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h8CNP/11/